# When performing a translation or rotation, the model returns to its original scale

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I used the `meters` option when loading the model. And want to move the building model by  setPlacementTransform. All went well for my model which is in `.skp` format. But it seems that when I try to move the model with another format like `.rvt`, the Model returns to its original size. This can be clarified by looking at the comparison of the grid on the scene. How could this happen ?

[image: File with SKP format, moved and everything OK]

[image]

```
// Option
viewer
    .loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables, {
      applyScaling: { to: "meters" },
      globalOffset: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
      keepCurrentModels: true,
    })

  this.translation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(
      this.valueX,
      this.valueY,
      this.valueZ
    );
    const angleRadian = CoordinateConverter.degreeToRadian(this.valueRot);
    let rotate = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(angleRadian);
    this.viewer.model.setPlacementTransform(
      this.translation.multiply(rotate)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening is this:

- When you're loading an *.skp file, it is already using meters as units, so the viewer doesn't modify the model in any way.
- When you're loading an *.rvt file (which typically uses feet as units), the viewer will apply a corresponding scale **to the model placement transform**, so when you later override the placement transform with your own matrix, you're basically removing the scale coefficient.

To resolve that, I'd suggest to apply any custom transformation to the existing placement transform instead of overriding it.

Comment: Hi Petr, Yes you are right. and I try to use your suggestion. I basically want to input the number intended for the position location. So with your suggestion I can't return to my previous position
`const xform = this.viewer.model.getPlacementTransform().clone();` 
        `xform.multiply(translation);`
        `xform.multiply(rotation);`
        `this.viewer.model.setPlacementTransform(xform);`

Comment: That may not be enough. If the model is already moved somewhere away from the origin, applying any scale or rotation will affect its position as well. You'll probably need to apply the **inverse** of the original transform first, or at least its translation component (to move the object back to the origin), then apply your custom scale and/or rotation, and then re-apply the original transform.